# Decide if it is a process or thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, process, void-pointers

Give a `void *` variable as input (can only point to a process or thread), I'd like to first determine its type and then convert it to that type.

How should I do that in C++? I know it's a dumb question, but I've never done C/C++ before and can't think C/C++ way yet.

**EDIT**: I need to achieve this on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Are you inside the kernel?  User-mode programs each have their own address space, they can't have pointers to the memory of any other process.  Perhaps you have a pid/tid instead of a `void*`?

Comment: Which operating system? What is a that "process" or "thread" thing that is pointed to?

Comment: By "process or thread", do you mean that you have classes that represent these things?

Comment: @MarceloCantos I'm looking for a uniform way to pass pid or tid in but will treat the ids differently. Sorry, I might not properly state my problem.

Comment: @TerryLiYifeng: and you have to funnel the PID/TID inside a `void *`, being able to get, on the other side, the ID and what type is it, correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Pointers carry two pieces of information: the location in memory to where they point and the type of the pointed object. With a `void *` this last information is omitted, and there's no way to reconstruct what type it pointed to. So, you need to carry along this pointer another value that specifies what it actually points to (you can use e.g. an `enum`).

The only facility somehow related to this task in C++ is RTTI, but it works only on pointers to polymorphic classes (RTTI usually exploits the vtable of the object to store additional information about the dynamic type of the pointer, but the vtable can be accessed and correctly interpreted only if it is known that the object belongs to a particular polymorphic class hierarchy).

---

> I'm looking for a uniform way to pass pid or tid in but will treat the ids differently. Sorry, I might not properly state my problem.

Well, this is a completely different thing... if you need to pass around your PID/TID inside a `void *` you could simply create a `struct` or something like that with a member for the ID and one to store if such ID is a PID or a TID.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of solutions.

For example, keep track of all the `Process` and `Thread` objects created. Store these each in a `set<void*>`, and check for the presence of that `void*` in the `ProcessSet` or `ThreadSet`. This solution just requires that you know where the objects are allocated.

Other approaches require some ability to deference.

Most obviously, if you have defined the types `Process` and `Thread`, give them a common base class and pass that around instead of a `void*`. This is basic OOP. You can then use RTTI to find the derived type. But most likely in this situation, a refactor/ redesign would obviate the need for this in the first place.

If you cannot add a base type, you could add a wrapper, and pass that around. This works even if all you ever see is a void*. This is similar to the `set<>` solution in that you require to know the type when it is allocated.

```
struct ProcessOrThread
{
    bool isProcess_;
    void* handle_;
};
```

All this really boils down to: If you know the type to start with, avoid throwing that information away in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

What system are you talking about? On Linux, I would say your question does not make any sense, because processes don't have addresses (a `pid_t` as returned by `fork` or `getpid` is an integer).

You could use libraries which wrap processes and threads as objects, like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) does (and it works on Linux, Windows, MaCOSX...). (and they you could e.g. use dynamic_cast or [Qt meta object system](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/metaobjects.html), if you are sure the pointer points to either an instance of `QThread` or an instance of `QProcess`).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is attach a `type` information to the process/thread structures.